# Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples when I processed "titanic" dataset in kaggle

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm a newbie in ml algorithm training, so I did a toy kaggle "Titanic" dataset training and followed the instruction of a linkedin video course named" Applied Machine Learning: Algorithms"
when I typed the following codes: the error occured:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
parameters = { 
'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}

cv = GridSearchCV(lr, parameters, cv=5)
cv.fit(tr_features, tr_labels.values.ravel())

print_results(cv)
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7740/1127236825.py in

```
  5 
  6 cv = GridSearchCV(lr, parameters, cv=5)
  7 cv.fit(tr_features, tr_labels.values.ravel())
  8 
  9 print_results(cv)
```

~\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)

```
 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
 62             if extra_args <= 0:
 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
 64 
 65             # extra_args > 0
```

~\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)

```
757             refit_metric = self.refit
758 
759         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
760         fit_params = _check_fit_params(X, fit_params)
761
```

~\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)

```
354     """
355     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
356     check_consistent_length(*result)
357     return result
358
```

~\AppData\Local\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)

```
317     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
318     if len(uniques) > 1:
319         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
320                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])


ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [534, 535]
```

I really couldn't figure it out by myself, please help me! thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the shape of `tr_features` and `tr_labels`

Comment: I got the same results when taking this course. Even when I run the code from the 03_04>End folder in the exercise files, it is buggy out of the box. My guess is that some python or library version is different now.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Code

From the exercise file 02_04.ipynb (download from the LinkedIn Learning course), notice the last line in the first code block:

`tr_labels = pd.read_csv('../../../train_labels.csv', header=None)`

```py
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

tr_features = pd.read_csv('../../../train_features.csv')
tr_labels = pd.read_csv('../../../train_labels.csv', header=None)
```

## Solution

Remove the `header=None` parameter from the last line. Your code block should now look like the following:

```py
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

tr_features = pd.read_csv('../../../train_features.csv')
tr_labels = pd.read_csv('../../../train_labels.csv')
```

## Source

I found a community answer in the Q&A tab from the LinkedIn Learning course. Below the screenshot I have pasted an explanation from one Maxwell Bauer:

[image: screenshot of the Q&A tab from LinkedIn Learning course]

> It looks like the issue comes from the reading of train_labels.csv. If the header parameter is defined as 'None' in 'pd.read_csv('train_labels.csv, header = None)', then the actual headers of train_labels.csv are not read as headers and are instead interpreted as the 0th row.  If you remove the header parameter definition and make the read function 'pd.read_csv('train_labels.csv')' it seems to solve the problem because now the function is using its default interpretation of headers (infer). This default makes it so that the headers of train_labels.csv are interpreted as headers. Here is the proposed solution: tr_features = pd.read_csv('train_features.csv') tr_labels = pd.read_csv('train_labels.csv') For what is worth, I diagnosed the issue by looking at how the csvs were being handled: I read the files using the above solution, ran 'tr_features' in a new cell, and then ran 'tr_labels' in another new cell. Running tr_features and tr_labels in different cells will show how the program interprets the csvs. As a result, I could see that the csvs' headers were being interpreted as headers with the proposed solution. If you then add the header parameter definition (header = None) into  tr_labels = pd.read_csv('train_labels.csv') and then run 'tr_labels', you can see that the header 'Survived' is now in the 0th row and not the table header. As a result, the length of the 'tr_labels' column vector is extended by one (making it have 535 rows) as opposed to the 'tr_features' matrix (which has 534 rows) - therefore creating the inconsistency. Let me know if this solution worked for you